# Update drop down list Shiny

Tags: r, drop-down-menu, shiny

I'm pulling a list from a DB and trying to update that list based on search results in Shiny. I've referred to a few answers here on SO but I haven't been able to get it to work correctly. Here's my code:

**ui.R**

```
library(shiny)
library(RODBC)
library(plyr)
library(magrittr)

cxn <- odbcConnect("DSN", uid = "myID", pwd = "myPWD")

showList <- sqlQuery(cxn, "my query string", believeNRows=FALSE) %>% arrange(., SERIES_NAME) %>% .[ ,1] %>% as.character(.)

shinyUI(fluidPage(

  # Application title
  titlePanel("Select Show Data"),

  # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(

      textInput("nameSearch", "Search by show name"),

      br(),

      submitButton("Search"),

      br(),

      selectInput("showDrop", "Select Show", showList)

    ),

    # Show a plot of the generated distribution
    mainPanel(

    )
  )
))
```

**server.R**

```
 library(shiny)

shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

  searchResults <- reactive({
    showList[grepl(input$nameSearch, showList, ignore.case = TRUE)] 
  })

  observeEvent(input$Search, function() {

    output$searchResults <- renderTable({
      searchResults()  
    })

    updateTextInput(session, "showDrop", "Select Show", searchResults())

  })

})
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 4):

The problem turned out to be moot as RStudio has added functionality for updating select lists with the function `updateSelectInput`. That's what I used, here is the code for future reference:

**ui.R**

```
library(shiny)
library(RODBC)
library(plyr)
library(magrittr)

#cxn <- odbcConnect("DSN", uid = "myName", pwd = "myPwd")

showList <- sqlQuery(cxn, "my query string", believeNRows=FALSE) %>% arrange(., SERIES_NAME) %>% .[ ,1] %>% as.character(.)

shinyUI(fluidPage(

  # Application title
  titlePanel("Select Show Data"),

  # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(

      textInput("nameSearch", "Search by show name"),

      br(),

      submitButton("Search"),

      br(),

      selectInput("showDrop", "Select show", choices = showList),

    ),
  )
))
```

**server.R**

```
shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

  searchResults <- reactive({
    showList[grepl(input$nameSearch, showList, ignore.case = TRUE)] 
  })

  observe({
    updateSelectInput(session, "showDrop", label = "Select show", choices =   searchResults())
  })

})
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd try to use a dynamic UI. I would not know if this is gonna work because I have no way to replicate it, but try it out and let me know what happens

ui.R

```
library(shiny)
library(RODBC)
library(plyr)
library(magrittr)

cxn <- odbcConnect("DSN", uid = "myID", pwd = "myPWD")

showList <- sqlQuery(cxn, "my query string", believeNRows=FALSE) %>% arrange(., SERIES_NAME) %>% .[ ,1] %>% as.character(.)

shinyUI(fluidPage(

  # Application title
  titlePanel("Select Show Data"),

  # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(

      textInput("nameSearch", "Search by show name"),

      br(),

      actionButton("Search"),

      br(),

      uiOutput("dynamicDropdown")

    ),

    # Show a plot of the generated distribution
    mainPanel(

    )
  )
))
```

server.R

```
library(shiny)

cxn <- odbcConnect("DSN", uid = "myID", pwd = "myPWD")

showList <- sqlQuery(cxn, "my query string", believeNRows=FALSE) %>% arrange(., SERIES_NAME) %>% .[ ,1] %>% as.character(.)

shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

  searchResults <- reactive({
     if(input$Search == 0) return(NULL)

    isolate(showList[grepl(input$nameSearch, showList, ignore.case = TRUE)])
  })

    output$dynamicDropdown <- renderUI({
     if(input$Search == 0) return(NULL)
     isolate(selectInput("showDrop", "Select Show", searchResults()))
    })

})
```

NOTE:The dropdown won't show anything if you do not click on the search button. But with some conditionals you would be able to show the full list if the user has not clicked on it.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be working. I'm getting 'Error: argument is of length zero' where the dropdown box should be, error: Error in if (input$Search == 0) return(NULL) : argument is of length zero

Comment: I was able to get it working on my own, thanks for your help though.